# A basic example with "constexpr" doesn't compile

Tags: c++

I'am learning C++ so I'am currently reading the book "C++ Primer".

I was reading some examples about the "constexpr variables" and I just want to try a basic code that I just wrote but it doesn't compile I don't know why.

This is the code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int j = 8;
const int *p = &j;

int main()
{
    constexpr int i = *p; // *p should be 8.

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says : "the value of 'p' is not usable in a constant expression"

If I replace the "constexpr" by "const" no problem at all but I think that because the value of *p should be known at compile time there shouldn't be any problems.

I don't know where I made a mistake.
(Please be tolerant my first language is French)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `j` and `p` are not constexpr, so how can `i` be constexpr?

Comment: What if there were some code that ran before `main` (e.g. a global constructor) that modified the value of `j`?

Comment: Change the other lines to `constexpr int j = 8;` and `constexpr const int *p = &j;` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the fundamental misunderstanding you have is the difference between an object being `const` vs `constexpr`. A variable being `const` means that it's *logically* `const`, i.e. the value cannot be changed once it's initialized. That *does not* mean that the value is known at compile time, which is what `constexpr` signifies.

For some type `T`

```
T t = {};            // not const, not constexpr
const T t = {};      // const, but not constexpr
constexpr T t = {};  // constexpr, also implies const
```

All good so far, but there's an additional wrinkle: a variable of integral or enumeration type that is `const` and is assigned a constant expression, is also `constexpr`. There are good reasons for this difference, but what that means is:

```
const int i = 42; // i is int, and const, so it's also constexpr !!
```

And of course, if you want to use an expression as a constant expression, it must have been declared as a `constexpr` variable or function.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. This is why it works with just another variable declare as  `const` but my pointer needs to be explicitly declared as `constexpr`. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The reason this does not compile is because `J` is not const or constexpr.

Also note `P` is "just" const pointer.
This means `*P` can not be changed, but `P` itself is free to be changed.
Here is an example:

```
int f(){
   int a = 5;
   int b = 6;
   int *p = nullptr;
   p = &a; // *p -> a -> 5
   p = &b; // *p -> a -> 6

   return *p;
}
```

I want to clarify something for `const` vs `constexpr`:

`const` is not `constexpr`, but some for some primitive types there is no difference:

This compiles:

```
const int j = 8;
constexpr const int *p = &j;

int main(){
    constexpr int i = *p;

    return i;
}
```

Also this compiles:

```
constexpr int j = 8;
constexpr const int *p = &j;

int main(){
    constexpr int i = *p;

    return i;
}
```

However this does not compiles:

```
const int j = 8;
const int *const p = &j;

int main(){
    constexpr int i = *p;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Ok but now, if j is a const int variable and if my pointer is constant (const int *const p = &j;) ? Now, the value of j can't change and my pointer will always point to j so what's wrong ?

Comment: @Louigi115 like I said `p` is not consexpr. niether is `j`. Read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Comment: @Louigi115 • `const` ≠ `constexpr`

Comment: @JHBonarius Great, thank you. Indeed it works when I use constexpr. But I still don't really understand everythings. Without using a pointer I have no problem if `j` is `const int`.  But why my pointer has to be declare like `constexpr const int *p` and not just like `const int *const p`. Like your link say, I need to have constant expression but `const int j =10;` is a constant expression, I don't understand why I should have `constexpr` everywhere.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a constant and a `constexpr`?

Comment: @Eljay Yes I know, but since at compile time the compiler can have access to the value of my variable, I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: @Louigi115 Whether the compiler has access to the value of your const depends on the compiler and on how the value is calculated. It's perfectly common for compilers not to evaluate a const at compile time, but a constexpr must be evaluated at compile time, that the reason for the difference.

Comment: @Louigi115 That's where you are mistaken. It's not true (always) that a const expression can be evaluated at compile time. const just means a variable won't change it's value once it is initialised, but when that initialisation happens is not specfied.

Comment: @john Ok, I see. So it wouldn't be correct to write a programm like this : `const int i = 10;`  `constexpr int j = i;` because we don't know when `i` will be initialized ? Even if it compile without any warning ?

Comment: @Louigi115 As cigien points out in his answer `const int i = 10;` is a special case. In that example `i` is a `constexpr`.

Comment: _"I don't see what's wrong."_  When the `constexpr` refers to non-`constexpr` things, it cannot be evaluated at compile time.  Sometimes `const` things are sufficient to be `constexpr`.  But sometimes things marked `constexpr` are not able to actually be evaluated at compile time, including the situation that the compiler is grumpy that day and just doesn't feel like it.